# Python: Writing a program to simulate 1D wave motion along a string

Tags: python, string, simulation, waveform

I am working on a program that simulates wave motion along a 1-dimensional string to eventually simulate different wave packets. I found a program in the book "Python Scripting for Computational Science" that claims to describe wave motion, though I'm not certain how to implement it (the book was on Google Books and won't show me the text before/after the code).

For example, I understand that "f" is a function of x and t and that "I" is a function of x but what functions are actually needed to produce a wave?

```
I= 
f= 
c= 
L= 
n=
dt=
tstop=


x = linespace(0,L,n+1) #grid points in x dir
dx = L/float(n)
if dt <= 0: dt = dx/float(c) #max step time
C2 = (c*dt/dx)**2  #help variable in the scheme
dt2 = dt*dt

up = zeros(n+1) #NumPy solution array
u = up.copy()   #solution at t-dt
um = up.copy()    #solution at t-2*dt

t = 0.0
for i in iseq(0,n):
u[i] +0.5*C2*(u[i-1] - 2*u[i] +u[i+1]) + \
    dt2*f(x[i], t)
um[0] = 0;   um[n] = 0

while t<= tstop:
t_old = t; t+=dt
#update all inner points:
for i in iseq(start=1, stop= n-1):
up[i] = -um[i] +2*u[i] + \
    C2*(u[i-1] - 2*u[i] + u[i+1]) + \
    dt2*f(x[i], t_old)

#insert boundary conditions
up[0] = 0; up[n] = 0
#updata data structures for next step
um = u.copy(); u = up.copy()
```

Comment: You really need to ask a more specific question. "I copied this code from a book and have no idea what it means" is not a good question to ask on StackOverflow. Perhaps try actually getting and reading the book, if you want to know what the book's code is talking about.

Comment: Well, I can't get the book (the library doesn't have it and the $55.96 price tag makes buying it out of the question) but I simplified my question a bit if that helps. I really only want two functions (I and f). Thanks, Amber.

Comment: Do you perhaps want to do some research on the wave equation? More specifically the [one-dimensional wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Scalar_wave_equation_in_one_space_dimension)? You need to understand the maths behind this before you can implement it.

Comment: I found this on the first page of Google for "Python Scripting for Computational Science" without quotes: frs.web.cern.ch/frs/Source/PythonBook2004.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The code below should work:

```
from math import sin, pi
from numpy import zeros, linspace
from scitools.numpyutils import iseq

def I(x):   
    return sin(2*x*pi/L)  

def f(x,t): 
    return 0

def solver0(I, f, c, L, n, dt, tstop):
    # f is a function of x and t, I is a function of x
    x = linspace(0, L, n+1) # grid points in x dir
    dx = L/float(n)
    if dt <= 0: dt = dx/float(c) # max time step
    C2 = (c*dt/dx)**2 # help variable in the scheme
    dt2 = dt*dt

    up = zeros(n+1) # NumPy solution array
    u = up.copy() # solution at t-dt
    um = up.copy() # solution at t-2*dt

    t = 0.0
    for i in iseq(0,n):
        u[i] = I(x[i])
    for i in iseq(1,n-1):
        um[i] = u[i] + 0.5*C2*(u[i-1] - 2*u[i] + u[i+1]) + \
                dt2*f(x[i], t)

    um[0] = 0; um[n] = 0

    while t <= tstop:
          t_old = t; t += dt
          # update all inner points:
          for i in iseq(start=1, stop=n-1):
              up[i] = - um[i] + 2*u[i] + \
                      C2*(u[i-1] - 2*u[i] + u[i+1]) + \
                      dt2*f(x[i], t_old)

          # insert boundary conditions:
          up[0] = 0; up[n] = 0
          # update data structures for next step
          um = u.copy(); u = up.copy()
    return u

if __name__ == '__main__':

# When choosing the parameters you should also check that the units are correct

   c = 5100
   L = 1
   n = 10
   dt = 0.1
   tstop = 1
   a = solver0(I, f, c, L, n, dt, tstop)
```

It returns an array with the values of the wave at time tstop and at all the points in our solution grid.

Before you apply it to a practical situation, you should read up both about the wave equation and the finite element method to understand what the code does. It can be used to find the numerical solutions of the wave equation:

```
Utt + beta*Ut = c^2*Uxx + f(x,t)
```

which is one of most important differential equations in physics.  The solution of this PDE or wave, is given by a function which is a function of space and time `u(x,t)`.

To visualize the concept of wave, consider two dimensions, space and time. If you fix the time, e.g. t1, you will get a function of x:

```
U(x) = U(x,t=t1)
```

However, at a particular point of space, x1, the wave is a function of time:

```
U(t) = U(x=x1, t)
```

This should help you to understand how the wave propagates. In order to find a solution, you need to impose some initial and boundary conditions to restrict all the possibles waves to the one you are interested in. For this particular case:

- `I = I(xi)` is the initial force that we will apply to get the
  perturbation/wave going.
- The term `f = f(x,t)` accounts for any external force that generates
  waves.
- `c` is wave velocity; it is a constant (assuming the medium is
  homogeneous).
- `L` is the length of the domain where we want to solve the PDE; also
  a constant.
- `n` is the number of grid points in space.
- `dt` is a time step.
- `tstop` is the stop time.

Comment: I made an animation of this code. But I get a strange behaviour when I get more then 100 elements or when I use to big time steps. Do somebody know why? See the code here --> http://pastebin.com/7itv0WR2

Comment: also problems when I change c and L.

Comment: You are having instability problems related with the CFL condition, this condition is a restrinction on the ratio of the size of the time step and the size of the spatial step, based on causality. Then, just reduce the value of dt accordingly with the size of dx, that is, inversely with the number of elements.

Comment: I did something using the code I've found here, it is on https://github.com/rvelseg/string_resonance